# dynamically change viewpart contents depending on selection

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to change view part contents depending on selection? I have a view part that is subscribed to selection events and depending on some conditions different set of controls is shown in the view.

This sounds rather like swing cardlayout, however I am not sure if there is an analogue in swt and I do not want to hardcode view contents in java code.

Something like eclipse command framework `<visibleWhen>` expression is really anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

I think [StackLayout](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StackLayout.html) is what you're looking for. It's very simple to Swing's CardLayout.

Comment: Is it possible to have declarative expression that will chose view part contents? I am trying to achieve something like `History` view where one view part may contain controls contributed with different plugins (e.g. `org.eclipse.egit.ui`, `org.eclipse.team.ui`)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have declarative expression that will chose view part contents? I am trying to achieve something like History view where one view part may contain controls contributed with different plugins (e.g. org.eclipse.egit.ui, org.eclipse.team.ui)

No, you'll need to create your own extension point for that. The good news is that [it isn't too hard](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html).